# Variance of a simple Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to apply Ito's lemma to compute variance of the following integral

$X(t) = \int_{0}^t W(s)dW(s),$

where $W(t)$ is a Wienner process. Could you please check my calculations?

$$E(X(t)) = 0 \\
E(X^2(t)) = E\left(\left( \int_{0}^t W(s)dW(s)  \right)^2\right) = E\left( \int_{0}^t W(s)^2 ds \right) =  \int_{0}^t E(W(s)^2) ds = \frac{t^2}{2}.$$

Hence, $Var(X(t)) = \frac{t^2}{2} - 0^2 = \frac{t^2}{2}.$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems to be correct. You used Ito isometry and the fact that $E(W(t)^2) = t$.

Comment: .... and Fubini's theorem.